# How can I rephrase this sentence to emphasize the underlying statement?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, phrase-requests

What are the better ways to describe a happy person -> (meaning someone who has everything he needs)
and opposite of that misery (but not quite) -> (meaning someone who is alive but living in hell)

> These are the ways a happy person turns his life to living hell.

Comment: What you've written seems OK to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking but:

"*It is always possible for someone to snatch defeat from the jaws of victory.*"  meaning that it is always possible to make things worse by making the wrong decisions.

You could use is like this:

"*It is always possible for someone to snatch defeat from the jaws of victory by...[doing this one thing or by doing these specific things].*"

OR

"*It is always possible for someone with a good life to make it much worse... by making mistakes like this...*"

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for saying the same thing would be

> These are the ways someone goes from having a contented life to a miserable one

Comment: I think that's less emphatic than the original (certainly "content" is less emphatic than "happy", aside from the rest of the sentence structure which rather buries "content" and "miserable").

Comment: 'Content life' seems a most peculiar juxtaposition. This doesn't seem idiomatic to me at all. '... a contented life', maybe.